# PhpStorm: trans(), view(), asset() Cannot find declaration to go to

Tags: php, laravel, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

I am currently working on a Laravel project and for that I am using [JetBrains PhpStorm PHP IDE](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/), and I've also installed [Symfony Support Plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7219-symfony-support) along with [PHP Annotations Plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7320-php-annotations) & [PHP Toolbox plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8133-php-toolbox).

> One important note maybe this would be useful:
> I have recently upgraded my PhpStorm IDE from version 2020.01 to 2022.2

Now the IDE has suddenly stopped resolving references, whenever I try to open any of the file type as mentioned below:

```php
trans('hello.world');
view('hello.world');
asset('assets/hello/world.jpg');
```

It shows `resolving references` for few seconds and then shows me an error `Cannot find declaration to go to`.
Previously I also was able to navigate to my routes and controller from blade files but now I am unable to do that too.

---

I tried googling this issue and found some solutions for the same, and I tried implementing and debugging it one by one, but none helped me.

**All my unsuccessful attempts as per solutions on the internet:**

1. I tried deleting the `.idea` folder.
2. Reinstalled the plugins, even reinstalled entire software too.
3. In Settings -> Directories, I made these changes (added `vendor` and `.idea` folders to excluded):
   [image: Settings -> Directories]
4. Settings -> PHP -> Annotations -> scheduled annotation reindex:
   [image: Annotations]
5. Settings -> PHP -> Symfony, now looks like:
   [image: Symfony Settings]

For this there were two solutions I found, viz. changing the fields. I tried changing

*Translation Root Path to:*

- lang
- src/AppBundle/Resources/translations
- src/AppBundle/translations
- src/AppBundle/Resources/lang
- src/AppBundle/lang
- app/cache/dev/translations
- var/cache/dev/translations
- app/cache/dev/lang
- var/cache/dev/lang
- ./var/cache/dev/lang/
- ./var/cache/dev/translations/

*App Directory to:*

- app
- config
- /app/
- /config/
- ./app/
- ./config/

*Web Directory to:*

- public
- ./public/
- /public/

Nothing has worked till now. I am not sure why IDE is not able to resolve references, and give suggestions or open any file.

Comment: Try installing [laravel-ide-helper](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper) and do `php artisan ide-helper:generate`

Comment: 1) `trans()`, `view()`, `asset()`  are Laravel specific functions. Navigation (file path resolving) for string parameters in such functions is provided by plugin for the corresponding framework -- PhpStorm does not provide this for Laravel/Symfony/Yii/etc specific code.

Comment: 2) Now, if you have worked with Laravel in older IDE version (2022.1 and older) then most likely you had **Laravel plugin** installed (that did provide such a navigation/file path resolving). The issue is -- this plugin is no longer maintained by the author and not compatible with 2022.2 and the IDE should remove it automatically (it cannot work with incompatible plugins). Your alternative is to use **Laravel Idea plugin**, which has much more features etc ... but it is not free (you have to pay for it). It well worth the money .. but still. Have a look, try it out.

Comment: **P.S.** Showing (and using) **Symfony** plugin settings for **Laravel** project ... seems odd to me.

Comment: @aynber laravel-ide-helper is already installed

Comment: @LazyOne yes I have laravel plugins. It all used to work fine but recently since after upgrade I am facing such issue, I opted for keep previous settings while upgrading.

Comment: @LazyOne is there no way to work this out without installing **Laravel Idea Plugin**

Comment: @Rajveer **1)** Laravel plugin is NOT compatible with PhpStorm 2022.2 **2)** But you can try this custom build (a fork that seems to work OK in 2022.2): https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7532-laravel/reviews#review=71677 **3)** For a better Laravel support (more/new features, especially for current and future Laravel versions) consider using Laravel Idea plugin (which is a paid one).